# Unable to open the app on iPhone Simulator --Appium

Tags: appium

I am using Appium version 1.3.6,Xcode 6.2 and iPhone Simulator 8.1 or 8.2.
Now when launching the app,App is getting launched but its not opening so it remains stuck to splash screen only.

Kindly provide me the suggestion to get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app from the simulator then deleting the built file and rebuilding the project.